# Что делает восклицательный знак в условном операторе?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
$("#timeline-1").timeline();

function slide() {
  h = $(window).height();
  $(".timeline-item").css('height', h);
};



$(".timeline").bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event) {
  scroll(event);
});

var num = 1;
var scrolling = false;

function scroll(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (!scrolling) {
    scrolling = true;
    if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0 || event.originalEvent.detail > 0) {
      num++;
       num = num > 7 ? 7 : num;  
    } 
    else {
      num--;
      num = num < 1 ? 1 : num;
    }
```

Comment: `!` означает `not`

Comment: знак ! инвертирует результат scrolling для проверки

Answer (score 1):

В условиях всех(большинства) языков в конструкции if ( здесь )
должно быть значение равно либо true, либо false
туда можно передавать что угодно, что в итоге даст одно из двух.
В том числе и одну булевую переменную

```
b = true
if (b) { // это равно  if (true)
...
}
```

знак инверсии `!`  вернет противоположное значение этой переменной

```
if (!b) { // равно if (false) 
...
}
```

Comment: Я бы сказал, в условиях меньшинства языков...

Comment: Да и про противоположное значение не слишком верно.

Comment: И? На каждый оператор по вопросу-ответу? Я за закрытие вопроса. Сайты хрома и фокса сожержат информацию о работе операторов. Гугл в вопросе "javascript восклицательный знак" в топ 10 так же сожержит верную информацию.